# How to configure @HandlerChain to point to a handler chain configuration file inside a JAR file?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Is there a way to reference a handler configuration file (e.g.: handler.xml) that is distributed inside a JAR file?

Something like this: `@HandlerChain(file="somefile.jar")` or `@HandlerChain(file="myhandler.xml")`, assuming that `myhandler.xml` is stored in `somefile.jar`.

Answer (score 5):

> For both server and client implementations of handlers using the
>   @HandlerChain annotation, you must specify the location of the handler
>   configuration as either a relative path from the annotated file or as
>   an absolute URL. For example:
>
> `@HandlerChain(file="../../common/handlers/myhandlers.xml")`
>
> or
>
> `@HandlerChain(file="http://foo.com/myhandlers.xml")`

Taken from [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxwshandler.html) doc.

Comment: Gonzalo, does it work even if the handler configuration file is inside a JAR included in my `WEB-INF/lib` ?

Comment: I believe the XML file needs to be in the same jar as the class that is using it, no matter where the jar is located.

Comment: Gonzalo, my problem is that the XML is in a JAR file, as a dependency (e.g: my-handler.jar), and the web services are part of a webapp that uses this dependency. So, I cannot put the XML file and the classes in the same jar.

Comment: I am not aware of any strategy to read the xml configuration file if it is in another jar

Answer (score 1):

handler-chain.xml file must be inside the same classpath or same jar.
You need to specify the actual location of xml to load.

Comment: Could you add some resource (manual, wiki, ...) as a reference?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no tight dependency on configuration file, you can skip it alltogether and handle everything in the code itself.

```
List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<>();
handlerChain.add(new MyHandler());
((BindingProvider) port).getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed when creating a jar, xml file was being excluded. So I moved my xml file to

```
resources/handlers/callbackHandler.xml
```

and then referred to this file as

```
@HandlerChain(file = "/handlers/callbackHandler.xml")
```