# How do I autmatically set a JAX-WS HTTP header that varies on each request

Tags: java, jax-ws, webservice-client

I want to set a dynamically generated HTTP header on each SOAP JAX-WS request.

If I wanted to set the *same* HTTP header on each JAX-WS request I could use the technique [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_cookiejaxws.html), i.e.

```
public class MyApplicationClass {
    // Inject an instance of the service's port-type.
    @WebServiceRef(EchoService.class)
    private EchoPortType port;

    // This method will invoke  the web service operation and send transport headers on the request.
    public void invokeService() {

        // Set up the Map that will contain the request headers.
        Map<String, Object> requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        requestHeaders.put(“MyHeader1”, “This is a string value”);
        requestHeaders.put(“MyHeader2”, new Integer(33));
        requestHeaders.put(“MyHeader3”, new Boolean(true));

        // Set the Map as a property on the RequestContext.
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
        bp.getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.websphere.webservices.Constants.REQUEST_TRANSPORT_PROPERTIES, requestHeaders);

        // Invoke the web services operation.
        String result = port.echoString(“Hello, world!”);
    }
}
```

However, here I want to use a *different* HTTP header for each request. Essentially I want to include a `X-RequestId` header or similar with a random value, so the receiving server can distinguish between requests duplicated on a timeout either by the Java client or (worse) an inline HTTP proxy.

Moreover, it JAX-WS retries the same call, I don't want it to regenerate the header (obviously).

Note that my application is already covered in the equivalent of `port.echoString` (lots of calls to the web service). I can't manually change the header in front of each such call because:

- they share the same binding provider, and this would not be thread-safe (i.e. user A could change the header, user B could change the header, then user A could call, then user B could call, and the same header be passed)
- this would require modification all over the code.

What I want to do is add something to the class that serialises each request, to add the header at serialisation time.

Questions that are related but are not duplicates:

- [java web service client, adding http headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666060/java-web-service-client-adding-http-headers) - does not use JAX-WS binding, i.e. each call has to be made manually
- [How to add header to SOAP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522931/how-to-add-header-to-soap-request) - SOAP headers not HTTP headers

Answer (score 1):

As for the unique value aspect, you can use the JDK's [UUID class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) to create a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier):

```
requestHeaders.put("X-RequestId", java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

As for the clarified thread safety concern, based on the [JAX-WS specification (JSR-224)](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxws-2_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jaxws-2_0-fr-spec.pdf) section 9.3  I'd suggest using a JAX-WS client handler to do this as the handler spec identifies a thread safe mechanism: [MessageContext](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-pfd/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html):

> **9.3.3 Handler Implementation Considerations**
>
> Handler instances may be pooled by a JAX-WS runtime system. All
>   instances of a specific handler are considered equivalent by a JAX-WS
>   runtime system and any instance may be chosen to handle a particular
>   message. Different handler instances may be used to handle each
>   message of an MEP. Different threads may be used for each handler in a
>   handler chain, for each message in an MEP or any combination of the
>   two. Handlers should not rely on thread local state to share
>   information. Handlers should instead use the message context, see section 9.4.

You can write one central handler class and attach it to the `BindingProvider`'s handler chain to avoid changing all the places you invoke the service operation across the application. You can add a handler to the handler chain programmatically or via the [@HandlerChain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908726/how-to-configure-handlerchain-to-point-to-a-handler-chain-configuration-file-in) annotation companion to `@WebServiceRef`

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639695/using-jax-ws-how-can-i-set-the-user-agent-property) describes using the handler framework's `MessageContext` to set outbound http headers like you want. However in your case you want to set the `X-RequestId` with the `UUID` value discussed above.

Comment: Right, but my application already calls `port.echoString` all over the place (many hundreds of calls). Your way is essentially the same as what's in the question, i.e. the UUID would be the same on each call (unless I manually add the header before each call which would require huge modifications and would not be thread safe)

Comment: The updated question clarifies a bit; are you saying `MyApplicationClass` is a shared instance across threads, or that you have lots of classes in your application that all have their own `@WebServiceRef` to `EchoService` (or both)?. Also, what jax-ws implementation? If CXF, there is apparently a way to make request context use thread locals: http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?

Comment: Updated answer to recommend JAX-WS handler and message context instead of binding provider request context. As for a way to do this universally with zero changes to at least where the binding provider is created/injected via annotation, I am not sure. If your application only has one/a few `@WebServiceRef` for this service then the handler chain approach does solve this.

Comment: I think this is (now) the correct answer. In the meantime I found `sun.net.http.retryPost = false` which is also useful (in the case where it's the client retrying rather than an intermediate proxy). Slightly ironic that the answer you point to is the one that generates a very static header!

Comment: Really confused at how I can input request specific headers value this way